# Displaying an invalid output in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I did the below code. But the final answer doesn't come. it always shows up as "invalid input". Can i know the reason for it ? :)  is it something wrong with my switch statement? Thank you so much. Have a nice day and stay safe!

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 function link()
 {
     var r=prompt("Enter the operation:"+'\n'+"1-addition  2-sub 3-div 4- mul");
 
     if(r>4)
     {
         alert("invalid input");
     }
     else {
 var n1=prompt("1st number:");
 var n2=prompt("2nd number:");
a=n1+n2;
s=n1-n2;
d=n1/n2;
m=n1*n2;

switch(r)
{
    case 1:document.write("Addition answer = "+a);break;
    case 2:document.write("Substraction answer = "+s);break;
    case 3:document.write("Division answer = "+d);break;
    case 4:document.write("Multiplication answer = "+m);break;
    default:document.write("invalid Input");
}
 
    } }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" >

</script>    

<input type="button" value="maths" onclick=link()>
  
<script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `window.prompt` [returns a string](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp), and your switch statement is switching on numbers. So you'll always hit the default. You need to parse the user input as an integer.

Comment: Also check for `isNaN` for `r`, `n1`, `n2` and set error if one of `n1` or `n2` is not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prompt gives you a string back you should use parseInt

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 function link()
 {
     var r=prompt("Enter the operation:"+'\n'+"1-addition  2-sub 3-div 4- mul");
     r = parseInt(r);
 
     if(r>4)
     {
         alert("invalid input");
     }
     else {
 var n1=prompt("1st number:");
 var n2=prompt("2nd number:");
 let x = parseInt(n1)
 let y = parseInt(n2)
 
a=x+y;
s=x-y;
d=x/y;
m=x*y;

switch(r)
{
    case 1:document.write("Addition answer = "+a);break;
    case 2:document.write("Substraction answer = "+s);break;
    case 3:document.write("Division answer = "+d);break;
    case 4:document.write("Multiplication answer = "+m);break;
    default:document.write("invalid Input");
}
 
    } }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" >

</script>    

<input type="button" value="maths" onclick=link()>
  
<script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert string to integer. Try with the below code.

```js
function link()
 {
     var r=parseInt(prompt("Enter the operation:"+'\n'+"1-addition  2-sub 3-div 4- mul"));
 
     if(r>4)
     {
         alert("invalid input");
     }
     else {
 var n1=parseInt(prompt("1st number:"));
 var n2=parseInt(prompt("2nd number:"));
a=n1+n2;
s=n1-n2;
d=n1/n2;
m=n1*n2;

switch(r)
{
    case 1:document.write("Addition answer = "+a);break;
    case 2:document.write("Substraction answer = "+s);break;
    case 3:document.write("Division answer = "+d);break;
    case 4:document.write("Multiplication answer = "+m);break;
    default:document.write("invalid Input22");
}
 
    } }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="maths" onclick=link()>
```